Nombre de la Branch en el costado derecho de terminal Git Bash
No se visualiza el nombre de la branch al constado de la ruta:
EJ:
Como se ve:
cesar.catalan@NBK-0001 MINGW64 /SCM/automatizaciones
Como deberia verse:
cesar.catalan@NBK-0001 MINGW64 /SCM/automatizaciones (master)
he reinstalado y persiste el problema

prueba con git branch -r

que sistema operativo estas usando?

Sistema operativo Windows

prueba con git branch -r – DavElsanto
Esto no soluciona el problema, tengo muchos repositorios y no puedo ver la branch en la que se encuentra mientras las reviso, tengo que hacer un comando adiccional para visulizarla

Con esto se Soluciono!!
export GIT_PS1_SHOWBRANCH=1
